# Can you put comments in Avro JSON schema files?

Tags: json, avro

I'm writing my first Avro schema, which uses JSON as the schema language.  I know you cannot put comments into plain JSON, but I'm wondering if the Avro tool allows comments.  E.g. Perhaps it strips them (like a preprocessor) before parsing the JSON.

Edit: I'm using the C++ Avro toolchain

Answer (score 18):

Yes, but it is limited. In the schema, Avro data types 'record', 'enum', and 'fixed' allow for a 'doc' field that contains an arbitrary documentation string. For example:

```
{"type": "record", "name": "test.Weather",
 "doc": "A weather reading.",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "station", "type": "string", "order": "ignore"},
     {"name": "time", "type": "long"},
     {"name": "temp", "type": "int"}
 ]
}
```

From the official Avro spec:

> doc: a JSON string providing documentation to the user of this schema (optional).

https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schema_record

An example: 
 https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/33d495840c896b693b7f37b5ec786ac1acacd3b4/share/test/schemas/weather.avsc#L2

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use C comments in an Avro JSON schema : `/* something */ or // something` 
Avro tools ignores these expressions during the parsing.

**EDIT**: It only works with the Java API.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  If I put either style of comments (/**/ or //) into the JSON file, I get an error: "Failed to parse or compile schema: Unexpected character in json 2f". I tried putting both style of comments in several places in the file.

Comment: I suggest that you have ever compiled your schema without the comments and it works. Check the following things : latest version of avro-tools, keep sure that your schema compiles (with the avro tools or [Json validator](http://jsonlint.com/)). For your information, comments work fine for all my avro schema...

Comment: I'm using 1.7.4 which is the latest release.  I think the issue might be that we're using the C++ version right now, and you're using the Java version.  Sorry to have left out that detail in my question.

Comment: Indeed... I just tried with the C++ version and it doesn't work. Thanks to highlight this avro issue.

Comment: Same with python package Avro. It internally uses the straight json loader to parse the schema and it fails if there are comments or any other "extended" json syntax.

Answer (score 6):

According to [the current (`1.9.2`) Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schemas) it's allowed to put in extra attributes, that are not defined, as metadata:

[image: Avro schema specification screenshot]

This allows you add comments like this:

```
{
  "type": "record", 
  "name": "test",
  "comment": "This is a comment",
  "//": "This is also a comment",
  "TODO": "As per this comment we should remember to fix this schema" ,
  "fields" : [
    {
      "name": "a", "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "b", "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it can't in the C++ nor the C# version (as of 1.7.5). If you look at the code they just shove the JSON into the JSON parser without any comment preprocessing - bizarre programming style. Documentation and language support appears to be pretty sloppy...